# Unable to login into OKTA application when using jmeter's recording controller (proxy)

Tags: jmeter

I'm able to login into the OKTA application, when I'm NOT recording the jmeter script using jmeter's proxy server(using Test Script Recorder). But, as soon as I setup my browser to use jmeter's proxy server (Test Script Recorder) for recording, I'm NOT able to login into the application itself. I see error "Please try your request later.The system is having techical difficulties". But the application works fine without proxy and i am able to login to OKTA application.

Steps:

1. Open jmeter. In test paln add test script recorder and change the browser IE Lan settings port to 8888 which is specified in the recorder.
2. Launch Application.
3. Give username and click on next
4. Error is encountered. "Please try your request later.The system is having techical difficulties"

But it works fine when i launch the application without any proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to import JMeter's self-signed certificate into your browser, the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start JMeter proxy server.

See **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) documentation for more detailed explanation.

Remember when something goes wrong most probably you can find a clue in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

There is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates, just execute your use case in browser and once done you will be able to export the recorded script in form of JMeter .jmx file

Comment: i have already imported ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt and it is present in bin folder.. the issue is it records till launchpage but after entering username and i click on next button in the ui, the applications throws en error "Please try your request later.The system is having techical difficulties"...

Comment: I am aware about the Chrome extension but in my organisation jmeter is the validated tool.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is due to the way Jmeter is parsing(and resending) the OKTA data(token, response etc.).The data parsed and sent by Jmeter proxy is unacceptable by the server and hence the error.Try saving the .har and then convert to jmx for jmeter use and see the difference.
Using Jmeter extension on Chrome might help too for recording.