# Why the application is throwing error when I execute a search transaction via Jmeter proxy, but not when I manually execute the transaction?

Tags: proxy, jmeter, certificate

I am facing this problem, and I suspect it is security related.

I am using Jmeter corelation recorder to record my scripts for testing,
I tried recording a search transaction in my application which is a document management system and as soon as I search(after Login) , it throws an error, while when I run the functionality manually it runs well.

Should I try forcing Jmeter to use my local proxy for recording or even playback(I have developed the script with Blazemeter extension as the Jmeter proxy recording was not working) ? The script however fails to playback the search transaction, server returns a 500 error.

I also see that Blazemeter extension has no problem recording the search transaction, which makes me suspect, that probably a security certificate is missing when I try recording via Jmeter proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Correlation recorder doesn't do any magic when it comes to identifying dynamic elements and coming up with proper regular expressions to handle them, you still need to do it manually prior to starting recording.

With regards to JMeter recording failing: yes, you need to import the JMeter's certificate into the browser, this way JMeter will be able to intercept and decrypt HTTPS traffic, see **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of JMeter's documentation on [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for more details.

If you add [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)  and see the responses, most probably your login fails somewhere somehow hence search fails due to your virtual user fails to login.

So make sure that

- JMeter sends the same network requests as the browser does
- all dynamic values are [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) is added to your test plan

given all above criteria are implemented you shouldn't experience any problems.

There is a 3rd-party solution: [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) which seems to be capable of automatically detecting and correlating dynamic parameters, if you're new to this concept - even if it won't resolve your problem fully at least it will give you some clue.

Comment: Recording (via Jmeter proxy)of login and other transactions is fine, Only Search is failing. However recording works when I use Blazemeter Chrome extension.
The script is corelated and I verified from LDAP logs that my login via script is successful.  Verified the content sent by Jmeter and Fiddler, it is same, even the Content header is same(I have tried other content headers too).The login via script is working fine, verified the LDAP logs showing login successful.

Comment: The error which I on server during the playback of search transaction suggests that, the script is attempting to do a "Full Text" search which is not allowed and hence the error is thrown. I suspect there is some setting or certificate component that is being used by my system proxy (and Blazemeter Chrome extension) but not by Jmeter during playback and recording(via Jmeter proxy). The search request is submitting an XML, and I have tried various content headers but in vain.

Comment: same problem with this one as well, it seems : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62875799/unable-to-login-into-okta-application-when-using-jmeters-recording-controller

Comment: Checked the errors, on server side and found that the error when I record the search via Jmeter proxy is exactly same as when the search fails in the playback. Makes me think What the diff between recording via Jmeter proxy and Blazemeter extension, proxy may be, but what else ?